# Spring Security and Java EE 6 Integration

Tags: spring-security, java-ee-6

Java EE 6 security currently leaves much to be desired (for me that's just saying), I however stumbled upon Apache Shiro and Spring Security as more popular security frameworks for the Java enterprise.

I am more inclined to go the Spring Security direction because of non existent tag library for the Apache Shiro alternative.

However surprisingly, I cannot find any tutorial that details how to integrate spring security with the Java EE 6 stack. Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to go the Apache Shiro partway. Tag library exists in www.github.com. And documentation seems appropriate enough

Answer (score 0):

As a variant: [this filter](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/servletapi/SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java#L30) wraps request implementing the servlet API security methods. So app level frameworks may work with requests security using standard API.

Weblogic AS has it's own [guidelines](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16764_01/web.1111/e14453/security.htm) for such integration.